# How do I find the first four terms of these two functions?

Tags: functions

Here are the two questions I am having trouble on.

1)  An=5a(n)      where a1=2 n>1

2)  An=a(n-1)+4   where a1=5 n>1

For question 1, I got (2,10,50,250) and for question 2 I got (5,9,22,70).

From there, I have to figure out if its a linear, exponential or neither as a function. Also, if its Arithmetic, geometric, or neither.

My problem always occurs when I am finding the first 5 terms. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

$a(n) = 5 a(n-1)$
and
$a(n) = a(n-1)+4
$?

If so,
your first answer is right
but your second answer is wrong.

The second equation
says to add 4 each time.
Your first term of 9
is correct,
but I do not see
how you got the
next two terms.